# Xcode app validation "You must supply an Apple ID"

Tags: ios, xcode5

I'm in a push to get an app I've been working on to the app store.  I was developing with Xcode 5.0 and when I validated the app it passed validation with a warning about using 64-bit architecture.  I want this app to be compatible with ios6.  Then I read where they fixed the problem in Xcode 5.1.1 - you could compile with 64-bit architecture and still be compatible with ios6.

I downloaded 5.1.1 and when I try to validate the app, I'm getting the message "You must supply an Apple ID".  I have gone into preferences and made sure that my developer account information is there and am validating the app using the same account.

Why would this error not show up under Xcode 5.0 but happen under Xcode 5.1.1?  And more importantly, can anyone shed some light on how to fix this?

Comment: Why aren't you using Xcode 6.1 ?

Comment: With a previous app, I upgraded from Xcode 4 to Xcode 5 in order to get the app compiled for ios7 and had to spend a good bit of time tweaking things for ios7 compatibility. Since I'm under the gun to get the app to the store I wanted to avoid having to recompile with Xcode 6.

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happened to me yesterday all of a sudden. I was doing the same thing I have been doing all along, the only difference is this new error message “You must supply an Apple ID”. I just ignored it and went straight to distribute it and it was submitted without any issues.